# Find which of the following functions is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, $f(m,n)=m+n+1$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

At first I thought about parametrization to make $f(m,n)$ into $f(m(t), n(t))$ so that I can transform this into $f(t)$ and work with $y=f(t)$. Also can this proof be done using partial differentiation?

So: $f$ is surjective iff for every $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, there exists $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y=f(m,n)$, right?

Comment: In general, avoid doing calculus on the integers.

Comment: @Randall Why? If a statement must be true on the Real axis, shouldn't it be true only with integeres too?

Comment: The function $f(x)=3x+1$ is surjective as a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but not as a function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Also, your definition of surjective is really wrong.  You've given the definition of a constant function.

Comment: What is your definition of surjectivity? Using the right definition it turns out to be a very simple question.

Comment: @Randall corrected it

Comment: This really is a very simple question. How can you write y in the form y = m+n+1? (There are many possibilities, which means that the function is of course not injective).

Comment: " If a statement must be true on the Real axis, shouldn't it be true only with integeres too?"  Not questions that pertain to the domain and ranges.  Restricting the domain changes the domain and thus changes the image. And question of injectivity and ranges are *entirely* about domain and ranges. And you can't do calculus on intgers as you can't have $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

Fix $y,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. We wish to show that $f(m,n) = y$ for a $y$ dependent on n.

We have then:
$$y = m + n + 1$$
Or:
$$ n = y - m - 1$$
So then $f(m, y - m - 1) = y$, thus $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get how easy and simple this is *supposed* to be.

To prove $f$ is surjective you just need to prove that for every $y\in \mathbb Z$ there will exist $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ so that $y = m+n +1$.

That *should* be trivial.  Just let $m= y$ and $n = -1$.

Then $f(y,-1) = y + (-1)+1 = y$.

You can always find such $(y,-1)\in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ for every $y \in \mathbb Z$ so $f$ is surjective.

Honestly, that is *all* the question was asking you to do.